# Dijkstra's Algorithm Implementation

Tags: javascript, graph-theory, dijkstra

So I'm writing a JavaScript implementation of Dijkstra's Algorithm.

I've read a lot from the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which has helped me translate the steps into code. I've also read [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597727/dijkstras-algorithm-doesnt-appear-to-work-my-understanding-must-be-flawed), which is part of my question.

> From A, the only path is B, this gives us
>
> O => AB = 12;
>
> O => C = 7
>
> C is now lowest distance, and is the new current node
>
> O => CD = 8
>
> Since D is destination and 8 < 12, the route CD is chosen.

How do you implement this decision into code? Right now, my script bases what node to choose on which ones are adjacent to the current one, does every decision need to be run through this new kind of evaluation?

By the way, [here](http://pastebin.com/4emAnLYv) is my (messy) code.

Comment: Your code looks a bit messy because you haven't used local variables for `currentEdge` and `currentNeighbor`. Also, you should first find out which one (`c1` or `c2`) is the neighbor node and then apply the condition on it instead of repeating that if-statement. Haven't looked further down…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> my script bases what node to choose on which ones are adjacent to the current one

No. Your `connectedNodes` list (sorted by distance) should be global, not only for the current node.

Then, for the first (least distance) node, add all non-visited neighbors to the list, still sorted by distance. Mark the current node visited and go on with the next least-distance-non-visited node.

Comment: Now the function spits out an array 13 spaces long with random nodes: [PasteBin](http://pastebin.com/CAuBEmzv)

Comment: Thanks for helping me clean up my code and have it make more sense, but this answer still doesn't answer my question of how to implement the decision. There is no clear indicator in my script that there was a certain correct or shortest path, just which nodes the algorithm looked at, and then what the final distance was.

Comment: To get the found path, you need to save the predecessor for each node you add to the list. Then you can go back this route from the end node to the start node

Comment: All nodes are connected to more than one node, so what do you mean, predecessor? The one last looked at? And how does this implement the shortest path logic?

Comment: Yes, the one from which the distance is measured. If you update the least distance, you also update the predecessor. That's how the algorithm works.